# PHP: foreach with 2 different variables

Tags: php, foreach

I have this little script to make a photo gallery. Now i want to add a title to each photo. How can i add a variable to this script?

```
<ul class="gallery">
<?php foreach ($foto as $a) { ?>
                <li><img src="images/<?php echo $a; ?>.jpg" title="<?php (second $var) ?>"/></a></li>
<?php ; } ?>
            </ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are are the filenames and titles stored? Do you have access to these in an array or the like?

Comment: They are stored like this:

`code`foto[0] = 'photo1¡;
foto[1] = 'photo2';

title[0] = 'title1';
title[1] = 'title2';`code`

Comment: Where do the titles come from?

Comment: I add it mannually into the $var, as they are not matching the name of the photos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you must push data into array like this:

```
$photos[] = array("scr" => "123.jpg", "title" => "My dog") ;
```

Then just use `foreach`:

```
foreach($photos as $photo){
   <li><img src="images/<?php echo $photo['src'] ; ?>" title="<?php echo $photo['title'] ; ?>"/></a></li>
}
```

Note the names of my variables. `$photos as $photo` makes it so simple as that to understand what is happening.

Comment: Thanks Jari, i'll try that and see what happens

Comment: i tried that, but it only shows the last items. It displays correctly the image and the title, but only the last one. am i missing something?

Comment: Just post your code, i will check it

Comment: Nevermind, i made a little mistake. It works perfect, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

$foto should be array like this:

```
$foto = array("firstfilename" => "firstfiletitle",   "secondfilename" => "secondfiletitle"  );
```

and then:

```
foreach ($foto as $a => $title)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try making and array with the variables you need, taking from $photo what you need and iterating through that using the foreach to have access to all you need.

If $photo is an object or array, just take the attributes from there

```
$array = array('photo1'=>'title1', 'photo2'=>title2)
foreach ($array as $key=>$val) {
    //your code here knowing photo1 is first $key and title1 is first $val
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your photo and title are both in array,then use something like this:

```
 foreach($photos as $key=>$photo){
   <li><img src="images/<?php echo $photo['src'] ; ?>" title="<?php echo $photo[$key] ; ? >"/></a></li>
}
```